# Where do Bigfoots live?

Tags: sasquatch

I live in Illinois and I know that Bigfoots like pine trees, but would they live here? Like maybe at the forest preserve or the park or somewhere like that?

Answer (score 2):

The Bigfoot or Sasquatch is a legendary creature that is believed to live in Canada and the United States. The multiplication of testimonies could suggest that it would not be about an individual, but of several hypothetical creatures.

the Bigfoot name was given to it by the first settlers during the conquest of the West, because of its presumed large size and especially the gigantic footprints it would leave after its passage. This humanoid being would mainly occupy the large mountain ranges (Adirondacks, Rockies, and Appalachians) as well as heavily wooded areas sparsely populated by humans (the Everglades).

Here is a map representing testimony of people seing them.

[image]

sources : wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

The being has different names but seems to be worldwide. In the Himalayas it is called Yeti, sometimes it is the abominable snowman but because so far the being has been able to elude capture so sometimes the very existence of this being is questioned. However there is so much of earth that is formidable and unexplored there probably are many life forms we have yet to be able to examine and prove their existence. This being seems intelligent because it has protected its privacy and existence. Illinois is fairly populated so a privacy seeker who likes to live in the wild would prefer to live more in the mountains or deep forest.